# Rotate a horse by 10 degree angle in x axis as well as y axis in Java

Tags: java, exception, coordinates, angle

I am trying to write a program in Java where i have some commands written in a text file, on the basis of these commands a horse will move in the same direction or changing its angle by 10 degree. Horse starting position is (0,0) and is facing east The destination is represented as a square centered on (500,0) coordinate. The square extends 30 meters north, south, east, and west of the (500,0) coordinate:

[here is the position of horse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyDqN.png)

**This is the command.txt file:**

```
Go
Hah
Go
Gaff
Go
Gaff
Go
Go
Whoa
```

**Command  Meaning :**

`Go`  Move forward 50 meters in the direction you are facing.

`Hah`  Turn left 10 degrees, but do not move forward.

`Gaff`  Turn right 10 degrees, but do not move forward.

`Whoa`  Stop.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class HorseRiding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Enter the path of the file");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = sc.nextLine();
        horse(filename);        
    }


    public static void horse(String filename) {


        File inputFile = new File(filename);

        Scanner readFile = null;

        try {
             readFile = new Scanner(inputFile);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Error! File not found!");
        }



    double x=0, y=0, angle=0, distance=50, x2=0, y2=0;


    System.out.println("The horse starts at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

    while(readFile.hasNextLine()){

        String line = readFile.nextLine();

            while(line.equals("Go"))
            {
                x += distance + x2;
                y += y2;
                System.out.println("Command: "+line+", New position: ("+x+", "+y+")");
                line = readFile.nextLine();
            }

            while(line.equals("Hah"))
            {
                angle -= 10;
                x2 = distance * Math.cos(angle);
                y2 = distance * Math.sin(angle);
                System.out.println("Command: "+line+", New position: ("+x+", "+y+")");
                line = readFile.nextLine();

            }

            while(line.equals("Gaff"))
            {
                angle+=10;
                x2 = distance * Math.cos(angle);
                y2 = distance * Math.sin(angle);
                System.out.println("Command: "+line+", New position: ("+x+", "+y+")");
                line = readFile.nextLine();
            }

            while(line.equals("Whoa"))
            {
                System.out.println("Final Position of Horse: ("+x+", "+y+")");

                if((x<530.00 && x>470) && (y>-30.00 && y<30.00)) {
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("FAILURE");
                    break;
                }
            }

            readFile.close();

            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting an exception error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1781)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Scanner.java:1610)
    at HorseRiding.horse(HorseRiding.java:40)
    at HorseRiding.main(HorseRiding.java:14)
```

moreover, it runs twice, till the second command Hah and then throws the above exception.

Comment: You are closing `readFile` at end of the outer while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the following snippet, here some other issues are addressed:

1. Simplified logic of handling each command.
2. Fixed calculation of `x2`, `y2` because `Math.cos`, `Math.sin` accept angle in radians, not degrees.
3. Added print of `angle`.
4. Added parameters for success point and range.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HorseRiding {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Enter the path of the file");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = sc.nextLine();
        horse(filename); 
        //horse("horse.txt");
    }

private static void horse(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(inputFile);

        final double distance = 50, successX = 500, successY = 0, range = 30;
        double x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0, x2 = distance, y2 = 0;

        System.out.println("The horse starts at: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        while (readFile.hasNext()) {
            String command = readFile.next();
            if ("Whoa".equals(command)) {
                break;
            }
            if ("Go".equals(command)) {
                x += x2;
                y += y2;
            } else if ("Hah".equals(command) || "Gaff".equals(command)) {
                angle += "Hah".equals(command) ? 10 : -10;
                x2 = distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
                y2 = distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
            }
            //System.out.println("Command: " + command + ", New position: (" + x + ", " + y + "), angle: " + angle);
            System.out.printf("Command: %-4s\tNew position: (%6.2f, %6.2f)\tangle: % 3.0f%n", 
                    command, x, y, angle);
        }
        if (x >= successX - range && x <= successX + range && 
            y >= successY - range && y <= successY + range) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAILURE");
        }
        readFile.close();
    }
}
```

Resulting output for the given sample file is:

```
Enter the path of the file
horse.txt
The horse starts at: (0.0, 0.0)
Command: Go     New position: ( 50.00,   0.00)  angle:   0
Command: Hah    New position: ( 50.00,   0.00)  angle:  10
Command: Go     New position: ( 99.24,   8.68)  angle:  10
Command: Gaff   New position: ( 99.24,   8.68)  angle:   0
Command: Go     New position: (149.24,   8.68)  angle:   0
Command: Gaff   New position: (149.24,   8.68)  angle: -10
Command: Go     New position: (198.48,   0.00)  angle: -10
Command: Go     New position: (247.72,  -8.68)  angle: -10
FAILURE
```